# the nature of pxebooting

Tags: networking, freebsd, pxe

Got a question regarding pxe-booting into freebsd. Let's assume the following.

- Machine A = dhcpd/tftp/console server
- Machine B = no OS (about get one by PXE)

After pxe-booting machine B, I expect Machine B being able to have network access.

Today I encountered something really interesting. I pxe-booted Machine B, but when I typed "ifconfig -a" I've found only the loopback. Which is impossible, there should be at least one interface, the very same interface that Machine B used to get pxebooted from machine A.

Anyone can give me some insight on why this occur?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A PXE boot/install process has several stages.
During the first stage the firmware contained in your NIC card provides the services of a PXE standardized network driver (UNDI).
That driver handles the first TFTP transfers like:

1. **NBP** (network boot program) i.e. pxelinux.0
2. **kernel** i.e. on the Linux world vmlinuz
3. **initrd** i.e. on the Linux world initrd.gz

The NBP after TFTP transferring the Kernel and initrd files passes control to the kernel which mounts initrd.

At this point (second stage) the running kernel will not use the PXE UNDI driver any more and it begins using its own network drivers. Here you could very well see that the transferred initrd **"does not include a matching NIC driver"** then on a console if you type ifconfig you will only see the loopback 127.0.0.1

As you can see while the PXE NIC driver can transfer the initial booting components, the booted OS might not include the required NIC drivers to continue its normal operation.

My example mentioned Linux but booting any BSD flavor also includes initial PXE transfers handled by the UNDI driver and next the booted kernel using its own net drivers (if available).